# GUID(contains hashes (non hex-encoded data)) in Dbus message

Tags: c++, dbus

I'am working on a project(c++) that have already dbus communication working well. I added one feild (GUID) in existing message. My application receives this message from outside. Then, if this message contains the new field converted to std::string all works well but the size of message is, logically, too big than expected. And if this feild is not converted and contains hashes that kill the dbus-deamon without any exception.
is it possible to send non hex-encoded data in dbus messages ?

Comment: i found this in dbus specification: _The string-like types are basic types with a variable length. The value of any string-like type is conceptually 0 or more Unicode codepoints encoded in UTF-8, none of which may be U+0000. The UTF-8 text must be validated strictly: in particular, it must not contain overlong sequences or codepoints above U+10FFFF._ but i am not sur that dbus allow other hashes even below U+10FFFF

Comment: i found the solution : in the API interface (xml) i changed data from `<arg name="Guid" type="s" />`  to `<arg name="Guid" type="au" />` 's'  means  string and 'au' means array of unsigned